# How to show an explicit size for a popover in storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, nspopover

I have multiple popovers in my app and need each one of them to be exact sizes. When I set each view controller an explicit size, the explicit size doesn't show in storyboard, but it does in the simulator.

Comment: Add some code / screenshots to your question, it isn't very clear currently.

Answer (score 1):

Select the view controller in the storyboard and set its Size pop-up menu in the Simulated Metrics section of its Attributes inspector to Freeform. Now you can adjust the size to match the size it will be when the app runs.

Do note, however, that the size of a view controller's view in the storyboard is completely unimportant. It has *no* effect on the app when it runs. The view controller's view is always resized to fit its surroundings when the app runs. The only thing that matters in this case the `popoverContentSize` or `preferredContentSize` - the storyboard is just a place to draw in. You should be using constraints in such a way that the fact that the view is resized when the app runs doesn't matter to you.